# How to change spaces to <br>s in a text node?

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey

I am writing a Greasemonkey script in which in one place I'm converting all the spaces in the text  into `<br>` so that the string appears more vertical in its cell in the table.

The HTML that I'm matching is:

```
<span>
    <img class="icon itemicon" alt="Manual item" ...etc...>
    Chapter 2 reading
    <a title="Sort in descending order" href="index.php....."> etc </a>
</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
var child = spanelm.firstChild;
var textChild = child.nextSibling;
textChild.textContent = textChild.textContent.replace(/ /g, "<br>");
```

My Greasemonkey script is finding the right element and doing the change successfully, but on the web page I see the `<br>` tags literally:

```
Chapter<br>2<br>reading
```

(In another place in my code, I'm doing a similar thing, which seems to work:

```
spanelm.firstChild.innerHTML = spanelm.firstChild.text.replace(/ /g, "<br>");
```

but I cannot get that to work in this case, with this organization of the HTML.)

I feel like I need to tell Greasemonkey to `eval()` the HTML or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text node doesn't have an `innerHTML`, so you can't insert new tags that way. (You should be very careful about this kind of string-replace of any node using `innerHTML` -- it's only a matter of time before the code trashes nested elements, inline JS, attached event handlers, etc.)

To insert tags in a text element, you need to break up that element into new text elements, interspersed with the tags you desire.  In this case, replacing each run of spaces with a `<br>` would use code like this:

([**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrft/))

```js
var precedingNode   = document.querySelector ("span > img.icon.itemicon");
var node            = precedingNode.nextSibling;
var words           = node.textContent.split (/ +/);
var parent          = node.parentNode;

for (var J = 0, numWords = words.length;  J < numWords;  ++J) {
    var newWord     = document.createTextNode (words[J]);
    var newBreak    = document.createElement ("br");
    parent.insertBefore (newWord,  node);
    parent.insertBefore (newBreak, node);
}
parent.removeChild (node);
```